# Why does '(function a() {})' not put 'a' into the global object?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, window, global

When [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064205/while-loop-wont-end-when-i-tell-it-in-javascript/7064252#7064252) another question, I was using this pattern to call a function recursively:

```
(function() {
    // ...
    if(should_call_again) arguments.callee();
})();
```

which worked. I got feedback that naming the function also worked:

```
(function func() {
    // ...
    if(should_call_again) func();
})();
```

However, with this technique, `window.func` is `undefined`, which came as a surprise to me.

If I put it simply, my question is: why is the following true?

```
function a() {}
typeof window.a; // "function"

(function b() {})
typeof window.b; // "undefined"
```

`b` is still be accessible *inside* `b` itself. So it seems like the `( )` create another scope, but that cannot be the case because only functions create another scope, and I'm just wrapping it inside `( )`.

So why does wrapping a function inside `( )` not put the function into the global object?

Comment: I don't know why the function is accessible by its name, but wrapping the definition in `()` makes it a function expression and even if they have a name, it does not create a symbol in the current scope.

Comment: It's probably evaluated and since it is not assigned to a variable, it doesn't appear in that scope.

Comment: Maybe the activation object created on function invokation has a reference to the function itself by its name. Even if you assign the function to a variable, it will be accessible by its name from inside the function.

Comment: For an explanation why the function is accessible by its name inside the function, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065120/using-functions-regardless-of-assigned-variable-names/7065175#7065175

Comment: @Felix Kling: I think that answers my question. `... the Identifier in a FunctionExpression cannot be referenced from and does not affect the scope enclosing the FunctionExpression.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're not writing a *function declaration*, but a *function expression*.

Functions defined in function *expressions* only get stored someplace when you assign them to a variable; you did not do that; you just called it immediately.

---

In a [very loose!] sense, you could think of function declarations as a special form of function expression assignment:

```
function a() {}
// vs:
var a = function() {};
```

This is still not a strictly accurate comparison, but it may help in understanding that a function *declaration* is kind of a special thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference that you appear to have overlooked, instead of defining the function as:

```
(function b () { });
```

It is actually written out as: (note the extra set of parenthases on the end)

```
(function b () { }());
```

When you write a function like this, it is immediately invoked and yet still carries its own scope.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, though. `(function b (){ console.log(1) });` does not log anything.