# How to collect responses from Facebook API requests in loop?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to collect results of FB API asynchronous requests which are called in loop. I use next code:

```
    function getPicturesByUserIds(friendsIdList) {
        var userPictures = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < friendsIdList.length; i++) {
            (function () {
                var userId = friendsIdList[i];
                var j = i;
                var friendsIdListLength = friendsIdList.length - 1;
                FB.api('/'+userId+'/picture?type=large', function (responce) {
                    if (responce && !responce.error) {
                        userPictures[userId] = responce.data.url;
                    }
                    if (j >= friendsIdListLength) {
                        console.log(userPictures);
                        sendPicturesAndGetResponse(userPictures);
                    }
                });
            })();
        }
    }
```

This code works in Chrome, but in Firefox *array* **userPictures** is empty.

Comment: `userPictures` should be an object (since you're keying using the userID), or you should be using the index `i`.

That aside, your loop keep  resetting `userID`, so all of your callbacks are dereferencing the same value - you actually want to pass the userID or iterator in via the `(function(id) {....}(id))` call you have to avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve those kind of things with "recursive functions", or - better - just use one API call for it:

```
/me/friends?fields=name,picture.type(large)
```

I would count recursive functions to the basics of programming though, you should get familiar with those. For example: [Calling a javascript function recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065120/calling-a-javascript-function-recursively)

Comment: Yes, it's the easiest way. Thanks)