# how does this recursive works and get this kind of output?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, return

This is a basic exponent function using recursive way.  I do understand how recursive works but I am having trouble seeing how this returns the base by returning the function itself

```
function exponent(b,n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }else if(n == 1){
        return b;
    }
    return exponent(b,n-1);
    // return b*exponent(b,n-1);
}

console.log(exponent(7,2));  //7
```

I commented out the real output because I was trying to see what `exponent(b,n-1)` means and I don't really understand is how does returning `exponent(b,n-1)` will give out the base as the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a javascript function recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065120/calling-a-javascript-function-recursively)

Comment: The case `n == 1` is just superflous. You could easily add another `else if (n == 2) { return b*b; }`, or you could (and should) omit them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is a process when the function calls itself.

The special conditions in the beginning, `n == 0` and `n == 1`, break the infinite chain of self calls, so once `n` reduces to `1` or `0`, the function stops calling itself.

So for `exponent(7,2)` it is:

1. n == 2, return 7*exponent(7,1)
2. n == 1, return 7

And if we combine the results it will be `exponent(7,2) = 7*exponent(7,1) = 7*7 = 49`.

Comment: oh ya! omg I just wasn't seeing it clearly.  Thanks thanks.  Really need to start thinking it this way.