# JQuery Loop Not Stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrvt5dgb/)

My script is to calculate a pension via putting in a fixed amount from the day you start employment until the last day based upon pension age, so my DOB is 25/12/1991 therefore if I retire at pension age of 68, it'll be on 25/12/2060.

```
function hello(){
  var i; var t = 50; var f = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < CalcY; i++) {
    f = ((t*52) + f) * 1.08;
    $('#collection').append("<li>Year: " + i + " Amount: £" + (f).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + "</li>");
  }
  TotalPension = ((t*CalcW) + f);
  $('#collection').append("<li>END Amount: £" + (TotalPension).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + "</li><br /><br /><br />");
  if (i < CalcY) window.setTimeout(hello, 0);
  hello2();
}
```

The first part runs through listing how much it'll be at the end of each year with an 8% interest rate gain and then `hello2();` is to calculate taking out money each year with interest gained on the remaining.

So `hello2();` I need to stop once the investment drops below money taken out each year which seems to be working partly but doesn't stop, it just keeps repeating as if it was calling itself.

Comment: This seems to be a maths problem, not sure what it has to do with jQuery?

Comment: Still it's not a question about jQuery :-) Have you had a look at a [loop tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code here instead of linking to it. Hint: a `for` head consists of three parts: initialisation, condition, and afterthought

Comment: "*How do I make it so hello2(); is only called once at the end of hello();?*" - it already is. Sounds like you want to make it called only once per sequence of asynchronous `hello` calls. Just add an `else` in front of the `hello2();` for that.

Comment: @Bergi I just tried this and updated my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrvt5dgb/1/). Still lists years 0-9 multiple times, I believe for each time the `hello()` is looped.

Comment: @Bergi I only want `hello2()` to be called **once** which should happen **after** `hello()` has finished.

Comment: Ohhhh! My problem is with `hello2();` which loop doesn't stopl....

Comment: your loop in hello2 end if t < f is false. So it ends when t is equal or bigger then f. Then you recall hello2 with: if (t > f) window.setTimeout(hello2, 0);

Comment: @TimMarshall you are using recursion, but you have a bad stop/exit condition. Also, in recursion, you need to pass variable initial values externally as function parameters/or as global variables depending on your scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065120/calling-a-javascript-function-recursively so which is your exit condition here `t>f` for which initial values: `f=TotalPension` and `t` is?

Comment: @loretoparisi `t = 125000;`