# Recursion in programming using javascripts

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Learning about function in javascript and i don't understand how the function is returning **720** as an answer to the operation performed in it.

```
function factorial(num) {
    if(num <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        return (num * factorial(num-1) )
    }
}
console.log(factorial(6)) // logs 720. why?
```

[Here is the link to the tutorial on tutorialspoint, under recurring function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_functions.htm)
I've tried working it on the firefox console, but still can't figure why it **720**.

this is what i think should be logged

```
function factorial(num) {
    if(num <= 0) {
        return 1; // won't return, because 6 is greater and not equal to 0 
    }else {
        return (num * factorial(num-1) ) // bracket first(6-1), 
           //then multiply by 6 (6 * 5 = 30)
    }
}
console.log(factorial(6)) // 30
```

please help, obviously I'm the one making the error!

Forgive me if this is a rookie way of asking a question on this site, i had to create this account in the hope of getting an answer, thanks.

Comment: `bracket first(6-1)` - this actually calls factorial function again

Comment: Well yes, `return num * (num-1)` would have returned `30`. But there's a function call in there! It's actually `return 6 * factorial(5)`.

Comment: You should learn what factorial means before trying to code it. :-) You may also want to do some research into understanding recursion.

Comment: The first time through it is basically `6*5!`, but the next time through, `5!` calculates as `5*4!`, then `4!` calculates as `4*3!` and so on.  If you follow it all the way back it would end up with `6*5*4*3*2*1` (ignoring the 0 stuff).

Comment: You might find this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv9NEXX1VHc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a javascript function recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065120/calling-a-javascript-function-recursively)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math problem, not a javascript problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(fractional(6));`

This will call fractional function and num will be 6.

```
function factorial(num) { // num will be 6
   if(num <= 0) { // 6 greater than 0, hence false and goes to else block
       return 1;
   }else {
       return (num * factorial(num-1) ) //return 6 * factorial(5); Here again factorial function will be executed with value 5 and so on.
   }
}
```

These are called recursive functions.Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/recursion-javascript) for more detail and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually read the description taken from the page you linked:

> Recursion is a technique for iterating over an operation by having a function call itself repeatedly until it arrives at a result. Recursion is best applied when you need to call the same function repeatedly with different parameters from within a loop.

That says it all. "having a function call itself repeatedly".
This line `return (num * factorial(num-1) )` calls the function again (repeatedly);